# QueryBuilder from one database does not read audit data created by other JaversRepository from another database

Tags: javers

Following is my problem.
Prerequisite:
Spring boot application1(SB1) with Database1.
Spring boot application2(SB2) with Database2.

### Both the application write javers audit data to Database3.

SB1 audits data for entity E1.

### SB2 audits data for entity E2.

QueryBuilder from SB1 cannot read the audit data for E2 correctly.

### It picks only NewObject type changes related to E2.

QueryBuilder from SB1 can read audit data for E1 perfectly.
QueryBuilder from SB2 can read audit data for E2 perfectly.

If SB1 can make a REST call to SB2 to get the 'changes' from the QueryBuilder instance in SB2 it works perfectly.

QueryBuilder from SB1 should be able to read the audit data for E2 correctly since the audited data is assumed to be agnostic to JaversRepository instance.

Following code is used in both the Spring boot application to get the audited records.

```
@RequestMapping("/javers")
public String audit() {
    QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.anyDomainObject();
    Changes changes = javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.withNewObjectChanges().build());
    List<ChangesByCommit> changesByCommit = changes.groupByCommit();
    return javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(changesByCommit);
}
```

**Following entity, repository, application.properties and 'jql changes output' was used in Spring boot application1 (SB1)**

`
    package com.test.javers.entitya;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityA")
public class EntityA implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "APPLICATION_ID")
    private String applicationId;

    @Column(name = "APP_NAME")
    private String appName;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_DATE")
    private Timestamp createDate;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "IS_AUDIT_ENABLED")
    private Boolean isAuditEnabled;

    public EntityA() {
    }

    public String getApplicationId() {
        return applicationId;
    }

    public void setApplicationId(String applicationId) {
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Timestamp createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Boolean getIsAuditEnabled() {
        return isAuditEnabled;
    }

    public void setIsAuditEnabled(Boolean isAuditEnabled) {
        this.isAuditEnabled = isAuditEnabled;
    }

}
--------------------------------------------------------------------
package com.test.javers.repository;

import org.javers.spring.annotation.JaversSpringDataAuditable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.test.javers.entitya.EntityA;

@Repository
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
public interface EntityARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, String>{
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sandbox1
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.password=postgres

server.port=8010  

#Audit datasource configuration
spring.audit-datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sandboxaudit
spring.audit-datasource.username=postgres
spring.audit-datasource.password=postgres
spring.audit-datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ { "changes": [ { "changeType": "NewObject", "globalId": { "entity": 
"com.test.javers.entityb.EntityB", "cdoId": "IEj5tvWc850834675" }, 
"commitMetadata": { "author": "EntityBUser", "properties": [ { "key": 
"applicationID", "value": "ViralSEQ" } ], "commitDate": "2019-06- 
25T19:16:02.946", "commitDateInstant": "2019-06-25T13:46:02.946Z", "id": 
1.00 } } ], "commitMetadata": { "author": "EntityBUser", "properties": [ { 
"key": "applicationID", "value": "ViralSEQ" } ], "commitDate": "2019-06- 
25T19:16:02.946", "commitDateInstant": "2019-06-25T13:46:02.946Z", "id": 
1.00 } } ]
```

`

Following is the entity and repository used for Spring Boot Application 2 (SB2)

`

```
package com.test.javers.entityb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityB")
public class EntityB implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "APPLICATION_ID")
    private String applicationId;

    @Column(name = "APP_NAME")
    private String appName;

    @Column(name = "CREATE_DATE")
    private Timestamp createDate;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "IS_AUDIT_ENABLED")
    private Boolean isAuditEnabled;

    public EntityB() {
    }

    public String getApplicationId() {
        return applicationId;
    }

    public void setApplicationId(String applicationId) {
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Timestamp createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Boolean getIsAuditEnabled() {
        return isAuditEnabled;
    }

    public void setIsAuditEnabled(Boolean isAuditEnabled) {
        this.isAuditEnabled = isAuditEnabled;
    }

    }

package com.test.javers.repository;

import org.javers.spring.annotation.JaversSpringDataAuditable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.test.javers.entityb.EntityB;

@Repository
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
public interface EntityBRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityB, String>{
}

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sandbox2
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.password=postgres

server.port=8020

#Audit datasource configuration
spring.audit-datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sandboxaudit
spring.audit-datasource.username=postgres
spring.audit-datasource.password=postgres
spring.audit-datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
------------------------------------------------------------------
[ { "changes": [ { "changeType": "ValueChange", "globalId": { "entity": 
"com.test.javers.entityb.EntityB", "cdoId": "IEj5tvWc850834675" }, 
"commitMetadata": { "author": "EntityBUser", "properties": [ { "key": 
"applicationID", "value": "ViralSEQ" } ], "commitDate": "2019-06- 
25T19:17:07.676", "commitDateInstant": "2019-06-25T13:47:07.676Z", "id": 
2.01 }, "property": "description", "propertyChangeType": 
"PROPERTY_VALUE_CHANGED", "left": "EntityB", "right": "WjMVxZBX" } ], 
"commitMetadata": { "author": "EntityBUser", "properties": [ { "key": 
"applicationID", "value": "ViralSEQ" } ], "commitDate": "2019-06- 
25T19:17:07.676", "commitDateInstant": "2019-06-25T13:47:07.676Z", "id": 
2.01 } }, { "changes": [ { "changeType": "ValueChange", "globalId": { 
"entity": "com.test.javers.entityb.EntityB", "cdoId": "IEj5tvWc850834675" }, 
"commitMetadata": { "author": "EntityBUser", "properties": [ { "key": 
"applicationID", "value": "ViralSEQ" } ], "commitDate": "2019-06- 
25T19:16:02.946", "commitDateInstant": "2019-06-25T13:46:02.946Z", "id": 
1.00 }, "property": "applicationId", "propertyChangeType": 
"PROPERTY_VALUE_CHANGED", "left": null, "right": "IEj5tvWc850834675" }, { 
"changeType": "ValueChange", "globalId": { "entity": 
"com.test.javers.entityb.EntityB", "cdoId": "IEj5tvWc850834675" }, 
"commitMetadata": { "author": "EntityBUser", "properties": [ { "key": 
"applicationID", "value": "ViralSEQ" } ], "commitDate": "2019-06- 
25T19:16:02.946", "commitDateInstant": "2019-06-25T13:46:02.946Z", "id": 
1.00 }, "property": "description", "propertyChangeType": 
"PROPERTY_VALUE_CHANGED", "left": null, "right": "EntityB" }, { 
"changeType": "NewObject", "globalId": { "entity": 
"com.test.javers.entityb.EntityB", "cdoId": "IEj5tvWc850834675" }, 
"commitMetadata": { "author": "EntityBUser", "properties": [ { "key": 
"applicationID", "value": "ViralSEQ" } ], "commitDate": "2019-06- 
25T19:16:02.946", "commitDateInstant": "2019-06-25T13:46:02.946Z", "id": 
1.00 } 
} ], "commitMetadata": { "author": "EntityBUser", "properties": [ { "key": 
"applicationID", "value": "ViralSEQ" } ], "commitDate": "2019-06- 
25T19:16:02.946", "commitDateInstant": "2019-06-25T13:46:02.946Z", "id": 
1.00 } 
} ]
```

`

Notice that the "NewObject" is appearing in both the output but rest of the 'changeTypes' are absent from SB1 even though the audit database is the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please provide some code or error messages you get

Comment: Please find the images in the order. Thanks in advance.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GA3b.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmUFM.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFztZ.png

Comment: I can send working code to the developer community that depicts the problem.

Comment: and what data do you have in the `jv_snapshot` table? in theory, if both apps share the same `jv_snapshot` table, they should get the same results for a given javers' query

Comment: Yes they share the same db but don’t  get the same output. That is the exact issue. I can share the java projects with the team if required. I have created separate projects for this purpose.

Comment: jv_snapshots have the audit data from each of entity from the two spring boot applications

Comment: I have found the possible problem area in the javers code. Is it fine to paste the screenshot over here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work the java application that 
fires the queries should have all the classes
from jv_snapshot in the class path. In the above case one has ensure that EntityA and EntityB are in the classpath. Then you get the correct output.
It means you can’t run javers query in any jv_snapshot without having all the classes in the ‘changes’ in its classpath or it will return only the “NewObject” change types only.